# using this rather than $(this) in an .each() call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've done quite a lot of reading this past day to get a deeper understanding of this vs. $(this) and how JS determines this as it interprets, but I still can't figure out one detail of a plugIn I'm analyzing to deepen my knowledge:

```
$.fn.plugInName = function(options) {
  return this.each(function() {
    new $.plugInName(this,options);
  });
};
```

Everything I've read indicates that although this.each() is used to call JQuery.prototype.each(), each object should be referred to as $(this) within the each() function, but the above uses regular ol' this, and I can't figure why. The $.plugInName declaration looks like this:

```
$.plugInName = function(el,options) {
  ...
}
```

Any insights anyone may have will be a big help.

EDIT: [Here's the full source on GitHub](https://github.com/logicbox/jquery-simplyscroll/blob/2.0.X/jquery.simplyscroll.js)

Comment: `this` is a raw DOM object. `$(this)` is a jQuery object which wraps DOM object(s). If the plugin expects a raw DOM object, pass `this`. If it expects a jQuery object, use `$(this)`.

Comment: `$.plugInName(this,options)` passes the actual element into the function rather than a jquery object for the element. It depends what you're doing with it, and it's probably for consistency is  that it uses the bare element (since the jquery pattern is for `this` to be bare), expecting that within `$.plugInName` you'll wrap the element `$(this)` if you need to.

Comment: You should probably give some indication of what `$.plugInName` does. The `...` tells us nothing about the function. But since you're passing a DOM element, I would assume that it expects a DOM element instead of a jQuery object.

Comment: I've spent a pretty good amount of time reading up on JS's prototype approach. I understand that every object has a prototype property which refers to another object and which can be assigned to an object you'd like to be a class's parent class. In this particular example, I just can't figure why you'd want to send a reference to JQuery's prototype (which I assume "this" refers to at the point it's used in the plugInName constructor call, unless I'm entirely mistaken) when $.fn already serves that purpose and is available

Comment: *"...every object has a prototype property"*  No, every *function* does. The objects created using those functions have an *internal* reference to the function's `.prototype` property. This is sometimes indicated as the object's `[[Prototype]]`. *"... I just can't figure why you'd want to send a reference to JQuery's prototype..."* It isn't a reference to jQuery's prototype. It's a reference to an object that inherits from jQuery's prototype. Big difference.

Comment: ...or it's a reference to the DOM element. I lost track of which you were talking about. I think you may be trying to absorb too much with a partial or skewed mental model of prototypal inheritance. Forget jQuery, and forget DOM Elements for the time being, and focus on learning how the inheritance model works.

Comment: So $.fn isn't a reference to the JQuery.prototype?

Comment: Yes, it is. But `this` is not. The `this` keyword is just a way to reference a value in a function. In the jQuery plugin, `this` is a reference to an object that inherits from `jQuery.fn` (jQuery.prototype). In the `.each()` function, `this` is a reference to the current DOM element in the iteration.

Comment: ...here's the deal, the value of `this` is not constant. It can reference absolutely different values depending upon how the function in which it's located was invoked. Don't try to understand how `this` works by inferring its value from code. That'll just confuse you.

Comment: Okay... I'm pretty confused. I thought you had to use .get() to access the actual DOM element, and as a result unadorned "this" wouldn't work inside a JQuery function, which is what the $(this) referring to the calling JQuery-wrapped element was for

Comment: And this is the problem. You're trying to understand how it all works by using a mixture of various jQuery functions. A DOM element can be obtained using `.get()`, because jQuery provides that as a method to return a DOM Element. It can be accessed as `this` inside the `.each()` callback because jQuery manually sets the value of `this` inside the callback. There's no such thing as an "adorned" or "unadorned" `this`. The `this` simply refers to some value similar to the way a variable can.

Comment: I think what cookie monster is trying to say is don't compare `each()` to `$.fn.`.  The implementations are different, thus `this` is different.

Comment: I know there are exceptions, but my understanding generally speaking "this" refers to either the calling function or to the newly-created object when the function is called as a constructor. In this case, it doesn't seem to be either of those things, hence my confusion

Comment: Right. In this case it refers to the current DOM element in the jQuery object, which is sort of like an Array of DOM elements. The value of `this` can refer to the DOM element because jQuery manually sets it. Sort of like `for (var i = 0; i < jq_obj.length; i++) { callback.call(jq_obj[i], i, jq_obj[i]); }`

Comment: I see... How can you know what a JQuery function sets the value of "this" to? It's not even in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: From the docs: *"...More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element."* [Here's a simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1mc122c5/) of an implementation of an *"each"* function. This one just stands alone instead of being placed on the `.prototype` of some constructor function.

Comment: @somecbusnerd usually `this` is the DOM element of the selector.  If you are doing something abnormal you could always check out the value yourself either using debugging/breakpoints, or `console.log(this)` and find out.    Just to confuse you :) … another thing you may consider is to use the plugin `each2()`, which is faster than `each()`, but instead of passing the DOM element it passed a jQuery wrapped DOM element, so that you don't have to do `$(this)` there are downsides to this, but in general it's much faster.

Comment: @cookie monster: that example JSFiddle was extremely helpful, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. The concept of `this` in JavaScript is a little weird. It's sort of like a glorified function parameter that is read-only and is set implicitly when not set explicitly.

Comment: yeah, JS's use of "this" is definitely pretty idiosyncratic. Ideally I'd leave JQuery out of it for now, but I've got something I have to get working pronto. Thanks again for your help. (@vol7tron also)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

> When a function is called as a method of an object, its this is set to
>   the object the method is called on.

When you call something like

```
$('#myDiv').plugInName()
```

the function is called as a method of the jQuery object `$('#myDiv')`. So, in this case, `this` already refers to a jQuery object, thus we don't need the extra `$()` wrapper.

A common case when we do need `$()` is when binding events.

```
$('#myDiv').on('click', function(){
    alert('You clicked my div!');
});
```

The difference here is that the function is called not on `$('#myDiv')`, but the DOM element that it belongs to. So, here `this` is a DOM object, not a jQuery object.

Inside the callback function passed to `each`, `this` refers to the DOM element, it is not a jQuery object.. which is just what `$.plugInName` wants. It expects a DOM element.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really wish people wouldn't say that `this` refers to the "owner" of the function. That's just not how it works in JavaScript, unless you consider the "owner" to be *very* transient. And since it's transient, the word owner loses any real meaning.

Comment: @cookiemonster I agree that "owner" can be misunderstood. I found a better definition on MDN, improved my answer accordingly. What do you think about it now?

Comment: @danbal: I think that's better. There are so many different ways to set `this`, that it ultimately comes down to understanding those various ways. I think that before the existence of `.call()`, `.apply()` and `.bind()`, a person could get away with terms like "owner" a little more easily, though still not entirely accurate.